# Render react-bootstrap modal onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I need to open ReactBootstrap.Modal window on click + to pass some properties to the modal.

I have my component with modal window content:

```
React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
        <ReactBootstrap.Modal show={this.state.show} bsSize="large" aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-lg">
            <ReactBootstrap.Modal.Header onClick={this.hideHandler} closeButton>
                <ReactBootstrap.Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-lg">Babe Info:</ReactBootstrap.Modal.Title>
            </ReactBootstrap.Modal.Header>
            <ReactBootstrap.Modal.Body>
        some body
            </ReactBootstrap.Modal.Body>
            <ReactBootstrap.Modal.Footer>
                <ReactBootstrap.Button onClick={this.hideHandler}>Close</ReactBootstrap.Button>
            </ReactBootstrap.Modal.Footer>
        </ReactBootstrap.Modal>
    );
  }
});
```

What I need is to create and mount this component upon user click + pass to the component some properties that depends on where exactly one clicked.

I did something like this in my click handler, but it doesn't work:

```
    var modal = React.createElement(MyModal, this.props.data);
    ReactDOM.render(
        modal,
        document.getElementById('modal_container')
    );
```

Any advices?